# App closing if bluetooth is OFF in phone in a connection with Arduino

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, arduino

I am working on an app which contact with Arduino and for this I need to connect it with Bluetooth.

I used the following code in onCreate()

```
 mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
    {
        //Not available
    }

    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        {
            if(device.getName().equals("HC-05"))
            {
                mmDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

If Bluetooth is ON in my phone then app starts normally but if the Bluetooth is OFF then app crashes and stops.

**LOGCAT REPORT**

```
03-10 22:40:24.521 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-10 22:40:25.069 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-10 22:40:25.069 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
03-10 22:40:25.069 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14665: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-10 22:40:25.069 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-10 22:40:25.073 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
03-10 22:40:25.073 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14669: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-10 22:40:25.073 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-10 22:40:25.233 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
03-10 22:40:25.237 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14565: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
03-10 22:40:25.237 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing     opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
03-10 22:40:25.241 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-10 22:40:25.253 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 495: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-10 22:40:25.257 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-10 22:40:25.257 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-10 22:40:25.269 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 517: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-10 22:40:25.269 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-10 22:40:25.797 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 179K, 3% free 10919K/11207K, paused 38ms, total 59ms
03-10 22:40:26.061 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 13.002MB for 2375580-byte allocation
03-10 22:40:26.153 989-994/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 3% free 13234K/13575K, paused 88ms, total 88ms
03-10 22:40:26.201 989-990/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 13235K/13575K, paused 15ms+30ms, total 49ms
03-10 22:40:26.385 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 13235K/13575K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
03-10 22:40:27.285 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 22.061MB for 9502284-byte allocation
03-10 22:40:27.337 989-994/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 22514K/22855K, paused 50ms, total 50ms
03-10 22:40:27.353 989-990/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 22514K/22855K, paused 13ms+1ms, total 17ms
03-10 22:40:28.197 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-10 22:40:28.197 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62ce288)
03-10 22:40:28.197 989-989/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol/room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                       at         android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                       at room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol.MainActivity.openBT(MainActivity.java:357)
                                                                       at room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: whats the crash log/stacktrace? (please add to your question)

Comment: sorry but from where i can collect log ?
I am quite new to android

Comment: Actually, this code appears to work correctly for me when I try it with Bluetooth turned off.  Seems like maybe the problem is elsewhere.  As mentioned above, the error should be in logcat.  If you are using Android Studio you should see an Android Monitor tab at the bottom of the screen which includes a view of LogCat, assuming your device is connected.

Comment: Updated logcat report please check

Comment: i updated the question with logcat report please see it now